# error "invalid operands to binary expression"

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
void Options::printHelp() {
    hash_map<string, Option>::iterator iter;
    for ( iter = options.begin(); iter != options.end(); iter++ ) { //<- this one
        cout << iter->first;
        cout << "\t";
        cout << iter->second.getDescription() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Definition of options

```
class Options {
    ...
    hash_map<string, Option> options;
    private:
    ....
}
```

XCode (Which is the IDE i’m using) marks the area "iter != options.end()" and gives me the error specified in the title.
I Can’t seem to figure out why.
(Option, btw, is a small container class, that holds 2 strings and an enum)

Comment: For God's sake use typedef, do you like to type hash_map<string, Option>::iterator and if you need to change container type search and replace everywhere?

Comment: What's the complete definition of `options`? If you're using C++11 you can make you life a lot easier by using `auto`.

Comment: Not that this will fix your problem, but you should preincrement interators (++iter).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Didn't know, What’s the difference between the two when in a for loop?

Comment: @Slava Yo, dude, relax... I’m using it one place, changing it everywhere is not that big of a deal ;). Besides, I’m from a Java background, being verbose is kinda our thang.

Comment: @SigurdB.Svela yo dude, if you use typedef you would not only make your code more readable, but you would not event create this stupid error. Comprenez-vous? Are you on java background like to use magic numbers and repeat them everywhere in your code as well to be verbose?

Comment: C’mon, take a hint, your being an ass. If you have a suggestion, I’m open to it. I started learning c++ yesterday and I’m indeed interested in learning. If you want to make yourself feel better with a pathetic attempt at making fun of someone, i suggest you go somewhere else, Comprenez-vous?

Comment: @SigurdB.Svela (again it won't fix your problem) Functionally, none. Preincrement requires the compiler to make a copy of the iterator before incrementing, which is ever so slightly slower. I also like it from the standpoint that it makes iterators stand out like a sore thumb, but that's probably just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly the problem is without seeing the definition of `options`. My guess is it's not of `hash_map<string, Option>` type.

If you write your code like the this though, you shouldn't be running into that sort of problems:

```
for ( auto iter = options.begin(), end = options.end(); iter != end; ++iter ) {
    cout << iter->first;
    cout << "\t";
    cout << iter->second.getDescription() << "\n";
}
```

Or even better:

```
for ( auto &i: options )
    cout << i.first << '\t' << i.second.getDescription() << '\n';
```

This requires C++11.